# How to Get Sum of Times

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with SQL Server 2014. My table has two columns. The first column datatype is datetime and second datatype is nvarchar with two type of data, fail and success. Here I provided a sample data:

```
 Column 1               | Column 2  
------------------------+--------------
2017-05-25 05:30:36.950 | Success  
2017-05-25 06:00:37.117 | Success  
2017-05-25 06:30:37.077 | Success  
2017-05-26 03:00:37.227 | Fail  
2017-05-26 03:30:45.143 | Fail  
2017-05-26 04:00:36.793 | Success  
2017-05-26 04:30:36.957 | Success
```

How can I get the sum of Success rows and the sum of Fail rows in time. For example, as you can see in the above sample data, I need a query that can calculate 1 hour and 30 minutes for success rows, and 30 minutes for fail rows.

Comment: which sql database and please post the expected result

Comment: please post expected result and actual result as text and also show your query attempt

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, I updated the text of my question.

Comment: what about expected result and also post your query attempt

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I provided my expected result in my question. I couldn't write a query to get the information I'm expecting.

Comment: look out this link for more info:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ on how to ask question

Comment: @TheGameiswar, unfortunately you don't know how to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this is what you need.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
    Column1 datetime, 
    Column2 varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData (Column1,Column2)
VALUES
( '2017-05-25 05:30:36.950', 'Success'),  
( '2017-05-25 06:00:37.117', 'Success'),  
( '2017-05-25 06:30:37.077', 'Success'),  
( '2017-05-26 03:00:37.227', 'Fail'),  
( '2017-05-26 03:30:45.143', 'Fail'),  
( '2017-05-26 04:00:36.793', 'Success'),  
( '2017-05-26 04:30:36.957', 'Success')
;WITH temp AS
(
    SELECT  *,
          lag(sd.Column2) over(ORDER BY sd.Column1) AS PreviousColumn2,
          lag(sd.Column1) over(ORDER BY sd.Column1) AS PreviousColumn1
    FROM @SampleData sd
)

SELECT t.Column2,sum(datediff(minute,t.PreviousColumn1, t.Column1)) AS TotalMinutes 
FROM temp t
WHERE t.Column2 = t.PreviousColumn2
GROUP BY t.Column2
```

Returns

```
Column2 TotalMinutes
Fail    30
Success 90
```

Reference: [LAG Window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is what exactly I wanted. Great.